# Running a batch script from a network drive

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, printer

I'm trying to install printers through command line which looks like:

```
start \\servername\\printername
```

I have to run cmd.exe as admin or it won't install drivers. This works well when running it directly through command line.

However, I put that command into a .bat file again:

Name: `printer.bat` with content:

```
start \\servername\\printername
```

Then I created a link to that file `printer.bat.lnk` and in Properties under Advanced ticked the "Run as admin" option.

This doesn't work and gets immediately canceled.

Any tips that can resolve my issue?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps a question of the current directory when executed?

Comment: It's in a network drive like O:\

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of your batch script to have it automatically run as admin

```
@ECHO OFF

REM --------------------------Start of getting superuser permissions--------------------------------------------

REM Check If the script has admin rights
openfiles.exe 1>nul 2>&1

REM If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
    ) else ( goto gotAdmin )

REM Now we create temp visual basic script which will run this script again with UAC
:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params=%*
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

REM Run getadmin.vbs which will run YourScript.bat with UAC
    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
REM Delete getadmin.vbs and exit
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin

REM --------------------------End of getting superuser permissions--------------------------------------------
```